# CardView: Let child item overlap

Tags: android, xml, android-cardview

I have a problem with my RecyclerView. 
I want to design some CardViews that looks like this:

[image: Twitter Card]

Therefore I need the ImageView on the top left to overlap the CardView. I already know the usage of negative margins but my problem mainly is

**Overlaps in Cardviews get cropped of even when clipToPadding is set to false**

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just set `ImageView` (Twitter icon) `elevation` more higher than `CardView` elevation.

Set `android:elevation="10dp"` to `ImageView` and set         `card_view:cardElevation="2dp"` to `CardView`.

**Here is an example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
            card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/sample_1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:background="#CCFFFFFF"
                    android:text="This is simple title"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_play"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: Thanks for your answer but there's a problem with that solution. It's properly working inside the XML-editor but it doesn't render.

Comment: You can try it running on your device. It will work properly. Your cardviewshould wrapped by another linear or relative layout and also use vardview top margin. Otherwise it will not show.

Answer (score 2):

**Child which have to Overlap CardView add this attribute to the child**

> Note : The child elevation must be greater than CardView elevation

```
android:elevation="10dp"
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of negative margin (which can be unpredictable) on the image, you can try to create another layout in the CardView to be the main content bubble, and add margin top to that instead.

```
<CardView>
    <FrameLayout
        background="bubble"
        marginTop="15dp">

        <!-- stuff here -->

    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageView ... />
</CardView>
```

Answer (score -1):

In Constraint layout..... I have done left side you can change according to your requirement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SecondActivity">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_box"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"


                />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="170dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="170dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_box"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: See in image here]